# Geofencing in iPhone

Tags: xcode, geofencing

I have written a geofencing app and it is working fine when it is running in foreground and background.
 And how to make that app work and send notifications regarding geofencing  even when the app is killed ?

Answer (score 0):

When the app is killed iOS will still monitor the geofences. If you enter or exit one, your AppDelegate `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will be invoked. You can then detect whether this is a location trigger with the launch options:

```
 if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey])
    {
       //Re-Setup your location manager and take appropriate action. The locationManager:didEnterRegion: locationManager:didExitRegion delegate of the new location manager will be triggered.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the notification at the time when you start monitoring your region:

```
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];

    UILocalNotification *regionNotification = [UILocalNotification new];
    NSString *notificationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are approaching near region%@",region.identifier];
    regionNotification.alertBody = notificationString;
    regionNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the region details.";
    regionNotification.region = region;
    regionNotification.regionTriggersOnce = NO;
    regionNotification.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:region.identifier forKey:@"regionIdentifier"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:regionNotification];
```

This notification will work for all 3 conditions:

1. when the app is in foreground
2. when the app is in background
3. when the app is killed

the callback for notification for all three cases is received in the `UIApplicationDelegate` method 
[- application:didReceiveLocalNotification:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:)

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    //Do whatever you want after you receive the notification
}
```